# Xcode 5.0 Watchpoint "sending gdb watchpoint packet failed" error

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing apps for ios and new bie to XCode.

Tried setting a watch point to a global variable. What i did was -

1. I kept a break point in viewload method and ran.
2. In the debug area I selected all variables which also list the variable I want to watch.
3. Right click on the var which I want to watch and select watch.

but this seems to be not working. Its giving me **"sending gdb watchpoint packet failed"** message. Can any plz help me?

Is there anything wrong with my flow? Please do advice.

Comment: Current Xcode is 5.1.1, not 5.0. I would suggest updating before trying something like this. Watchpoints have always been iffy; even now you can only have a couple of them. The fact that you get a message mentioning "gdb" is a bit disturbing, since the current debugger is LLDB, not GDB.

Comment: I do agree. The fact that I get a GDB watchpoint message instead of LLDB making me uneasy.

Answer (score 2):

I'll bet your project included another project that you needed to check. I just hit this problem working with a cross-platform framework (wdl-ol), which includes frameworks for a drawing engine (lice) and plug-ins (AU, VST...). My project was set up fine.

For the others, LLVM was the chosen compiler ("Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" set to "Apple LLVM 7.0"), but scrolling down to the "C Language Dialect" setting (under Apple LLVM 7.0 - Language", my my case) in the Build Settings revealed that they were set to "GNU99". Changing them to "Compiler Default" and rebuilding fixed it—watchpoints worked after that.

This is an old question, but unanswered and still relevant to today's Xcode.